# How to hide series name from tooltip in Highcharts scatter plots for linear regression

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, tooltip

I use Highcharts 4.2.3 to create a chart for linear regression. I am following  this demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-regression/

This is the code in the demo:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        min: -0.5,
        max: 5.5
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Scatter plot with regression line'
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Regression Line',
        data: [[0, 1.11], [5, 4.51]],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 0
            }
        },
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }, {
        type: 'scatter',
        name: 'Observations',
        data: [1, 1.5, 2.8, 3.5, 3.9, 4.2],
        marker: {
            radius: 4
        }
    }]
});
```

I am trying to hide the series name `Observations` in tooltips for the scatter plot, but failed to make it work. I am not sure where to put this code:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    return this.x + ', ' + this.y;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to have a tooltip formatter function that returns just `this.x + ', ' + this.y`.

See the [Tooltip Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip) for reference. Demo below.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        min: -0.5,
        max: 5.5
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Scatter plot with regression line'
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Regression Line',
        data: [[0, 1.11], [5, 4.51]],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 0
            }
        },
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }, {
        type: 'scatter',
        name: 'Observations',
        data: [1, 1.5, 2.8, 3.5, 3.9, 4.2],
        marker: {
            radius: 4
        }
    }],
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return this.x + ', ' + this.y;
      }
    },
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've inlined your answer and made it more intelligible, and there's an even simpler solution: use `tooltip.pointFormatter: '{point.x}, {point.y}'`.